# How do I communicate between a SwiftUI view to another when a coordinator is involved?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. Just a few days trying to learn.
I have tried to find a tutorial on this but I was not successfull.

Imagine I have the following view:

```
Struct MyPicker: View {
```

`MyPicker` is inside a `VStack` inside `ContentView`.
I have to pass, from `MyPicker` to `ContentView`, 3 parameters: `color`, `width` and `type`.

The problem is that these values come from a delegate callback inside `MyPicker`. So I have to have a coordinator inside `MyPicker`.

```
struct MyPickerHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
  class Coordinator:NSObject, MyPickerDelegate {
    var color:UIColor
    var width:CGFloat
    var type:PKInkingTool.InkType 

    func toolPickerSelectedToolDidChange(_ toolPicker: PKToolPicker) {
      if toolPicker.selectedTool is PKInkingTool {
        let tool = toolPicker.selectedTool as! PKInkingTool
        self.color = tool.color
        self.width = tool.width
        self.type = tool.inkType
      }
    }
```

Theare are a lot of stuff like `@Binding`, `@Published`, `@State`, etc. What do I put where to make MyPicker communicate changes to `ContentView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have state as source of truth in parent view and pass binding to it into representable view, which... here is an example for one parameter...

```
struct MyPicker: View {
   @State private var color: UIColor = .clear   // << source

   var body: some View {
      MyPickerHelper(color: $color)     // << pass binding
   }
}
```

and now in representable

```
struct MyPickerHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var color: UIColor

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
     Coordinator(owner: self)
  }

  ...

  class Coordinator:NSObject, MyPickerDelegate {
    private var owner: MyPickerHelper

    init(owner: MyPickerHelper) {
      self.owner = owner
    }

    func toolPickerSelectedToolDidChange(_ toolPicker: PKToolPicker) {
      if toolPicker.selectedTool is PKInkingTool {
        let tool = toolPicker.selectedTool as! PKInkingTool

        self.owner.color = tool.color         // << here update via binding !!!
      }
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that but suppose I use `MyPicker` on `ContentView`. How will this later be informed of changes on the first one? NOTE: I do not understand the need for the `owner` property. Care to explain? Thanks