# Pass data from ViewController to Representable SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewcontroller, avcaptureoutput

I am doing an object detection and used `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to add my view controller. The thing is that I can't pass data from my `ViewController` to my SwiftUI view. I can print it tho.

Can someone help me? This is my code:

```
//

import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import UIKit
import Vision
let SVWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

struct MaskDetectionView: View {
    let hasMaskColor = Color.green
    let noMaskColor = Color.red
    let shadowColor = Color.gray
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Please place your head inside the bounded box.")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                Text("For better result, show your entire face.")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
            }.padding(.top, 10)
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                SwiftUIViewController()
                    .frame(width: SVWidth - 30, height: SVWidth + 30, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .shadow(color: hasMaskColor, radius: 7, x: 0, y: 0)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                Spacer()

///      VALUE HERE
            }

        }.padding()
    }
}

struct MaskDetectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MaskDetectionView()
        
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    
    var result = String()
    //ALL THE OBJECTS
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // 1 - start session
        let capture_session = AVCaptureSession()
        //capture_session.sessionPreset = .vga640x480
        
        // 2 - set the device front & add input
        guard let capture_device = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) else {return}
        
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: capture_device) else { return }
        capture_session.addInput(input)
        
        // 3 - the layer on screen that shows the picture
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: capture_session)
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame.size = CGSize(width: SVWidth, height: SVWidth + 40)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        
        // 4 - run the session
        capture_session.startRunning()
        
        // 5 - the produced output aka image or video
        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        capture_session.addOutput(dataOutput)
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        // our model
        
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: SqueezeNet(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).model) else { return }
        // request for our model
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in
            if let error = err {
                print("failed to detect faces:", error)
                return
                
            }
            //result
            guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {return}
            guard let first_observation = results.first else {return}
            
            self.result = first_observation.identifier
            print(self.result)
            
        }
        
        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {return}
        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }

}






struct SwiftUIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController{
        return ViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I see no code in `makeUIViewController` or `updateUIViewController ` for actually passing data. Is there a reason you haven't add it?

Comment: Hi. I don't know how to do it. I am a data scientist and just a beginner in iOS. I just need to have the camera in my app and below it I wanna get the result my coreML model predicts.

Comment: Can you please help me how can I make it happen? I have been over almost all posts in stack overflow but couldn't find anything... :((

Comment: What kind of data do you want to pass to the view controller? Where does that data originates from?

Comment: Well basically I have the SqueezNet model. In the view controller, I have my custom camera, right? Then my SqueezNet will predict items in the ViewController as you see, and then I want the prediction `String` to be shown in my view. I can print that value but I cannot pass it outside to my SwiftUI view. I think the problem is because it is inside a function? I have no idea

Comment: Binding is two-directional way... you just need to transfer it inside your view controller. Here is an example of solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63942901/12299030.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to circulate a `Binding` instance through the UI hierarchy - this includes both the SwiftUI and the UIKit code. The `Binding` will transparently update the data on all views that are connected to it, regardless of who did the change.

A diagram of the data flow could look similar to this:
[image]

OK, getting to the implementation details, first things first you need a `@State` to store data that will come from the UIKit side, in order to make it available for updates to the view controller,:

```swift
struct MaskDetectionView: View {
    @State var clasificationIdentifier: String = ""
```

Next, you need to pass this to both the view controller and the SwiftUI view:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ...
    SwiftUIViewController(identifier: $clasificationIdentifier)
    ...
    // this is the "VALUE HERE" from your question
    Text("Clasification identifier: \(clasificationIdentifier)")
```

Now, that you are properly injecting the binding, you'll need to update the UIKit side of the code to allow the binding to be received.

Update your view representable to look something like this:

```swift
struct SwiftUIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    // this is the binding that is received from the SwiftUI side
    let identifier: Binding<String>
    
    // this will be the delegate of the view controller, it's role is to allow
    // the data transfer from UIKit to SwiftUI
    class Coordinator: ViewControllerDelegate {
        let identifierBinding: Binding<String>
        
        init(identifierBinding: Binding<String>) {
            self.identifierBinding = identifierBinding
        }
        
        func clasificationOccured(_ viewController: ViewController, identifier: String) {
            // whenever the view controller notifies it's delegate about receiving a new idenfifier
            // the line below will propagate the change up to SwiftUI
            identifierBinding.wrappedValue = identifier
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController{
        let vc = ViewController()
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        // update the controller data, if needed
    }
    
    // this is very important, this coordinator will be used in `makeUIViewController`
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(identifierBinding: identifier)
    }
}
```

The last piece of the puzzle is to write the code for the view controller delegate, and the code that makes use of that delegate:

```swift
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func clasificationOccured(_ viewController: ViewController, identifier: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    ...

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        ...
  
        print(self.result)

        // let's tell the delegate we found a new clasification
        // the delegate, aka the Coordinator will then update the Binding
        // the Binding will update the State, and this change will be
        // propagate to the Text() element from the SwiftUI view
        delegate?.clasificationOccured(self, identifier: self.result)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift has multiple ways to enable you to pass data back and forth between views and objects**

Such as **delegation**, **Key-Value-Observation**, or, specifically for SwiftUI, **property wrappers** such as @State, @Binding, @ObservableObject and @ObservedObject. However, when it comes to showing your data in a SwiftUI view, you are going to need property wrappers.

If you want to do it the SwiftUI way, you may want to take a look at `@State` and `@Binding` property wrappers as well as how to use coordinators with your `UIViewControllerRepresentable` struct. Add a `@State` property to the SwiftUI view and pass it as a binding to your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

```
//Declare a new property in struct MaskDetectionView and pass it to SwiftUIViewController as a binding
@State var string result = ""
...
SwiftUIViewController(resultText: $result)

//Add your new binding as a property in the SwiftUIViewController struct
@Binding var string resultText
```

That way you expose a piece of the SwiftUI view (the result string you can use within a `Text` view for instance) to the `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. From there, you can either pass it down further to `ViewController` and/or have a look at the following article about coordinators: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/using-coordinators-to-manage-swiftui-view-controllers

In my opinion, encapsulating your camera work inside another class `ViewController` is obsolete and can be done just as well by using a coordinator. The following steps should assist you in getting your view controller up and running:

1. Create your view controller code in `makeUIView`, including setting up the AVKit object
2. Make sure to put `context.coordinator` as the delegate instead of `self`
3. Create a nested class `Coordinator` inside the `SwiftUIViewController` and declare that class your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`
4. Add a property to the coordinator to hold an instance of your view controller object and implement the initializer and `makeCoordinator` functions to have the coordinator store a reference to your view controller
5. If set up correctly so far, you can now implement your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` delegation functions in the coordinator class and update the view controller's binding property when detecting something and return a result

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The thing is that I wanna pass data from `func` inside `ViewController` to `MaskDetectionView`, contrary to what you said. Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: That' what a `@Binding` is for. When you pass a `@State` variable to other objects as a binding, the state will automatically update whenever the binding changes, and vice versa. SwiftUI heavily relies on that conpect, because every view that uses a state variable is automatically updated every time the state's content changes

Answer (score 1):

protocol (interface in other language) make easy life in such use case, its also really simple to use

1 - define a protocol at suitable place

2 - implement at required view(class, struct)

3 - pass implemented object reference to caller class or struct

example - > below

```
//Protocol
protocol MyDataReceiverDelegte {
  func dataReceived(data:String) //any type of data as your need, I choose String
}

struct MaskDetectionView: View, MyDataReceiverDelegte { // implementer struct
   func dataReceived(data:String){
     //write your code here to process received data
     print(data)
   }
var body: some View {
     //your views comes here
     VStack(alignment: .center) {
         SwiftUIViewController(parent:self)
     }
  }
}

//custom view
struct SwiftUIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   let parent:MaskDetectionView
   func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController{
    return ViewController(delegate:parent)
   }

   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
    
}
}


//caller class
//i omit your code for simpilicity
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    let delegate: MyDataReceiverDelegte
  init(delegate d: MyDataReceiverDelegte) {
      self.delegate = d
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //your code comes here
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        //your rest of code comes here ,
    delegate.dataReceived("Data you want to pass to parent view")
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS A LOOOTTTTTT!!!! You're a genius... I am so happy. But one more question, I now have the data inside a void function. How can I take it out of there? I wanna use it inside my `var body: some View {}`?

Comment: Define a **@State** property and assign it in **dataReceived(_:_)** method  and also put this property in view inside body....Please read docs and there are lot of articles about SWIFTUI,STATE variables

Comment: The delegate stuff won't work because: 1: delegates need to be `weak`, otherwise you run into retain cycles; 2: you cannot have a struct as a delegate, structs are copied when assigned, so you'll not be referencing the same view